# Comparing classes that contains two numbers

Tags: java, math

So, I have a class that contains two numbers, more exactly `X` and `Z`. I'm storing it on a `TreeMap`, that needs the key class implement `Comparable`. The problem is, how am I going to compare the `X` and `Z` to other class on the `compareTo()` method?

I have already tried to add up the `X` and `Z` integers for the both classes and comparing them with `Integer.compare()`, but this is not a good solution because if `X` and `Z` are switched, it will end on the same result.

```
public class Position2D implements Comparable<Position2D> {

    private int x, z;

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Position2D position2D) {
        int coordinatesSum = this.getX() + this.getZ();
        int otherCoordinatesSum = position2D.getX() + position2D.getZ();
        return Integer.compare(coordinatesSum, otherCoordinatesSum);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please define the expected behaviour of the comparison

Comment: Would a lexicographic comparison be ok?

Comment: @harold I don't really know about lexicographic comparisons, can you tell me what they are? Appreciated.

Comment: If X = 0 and Z = 0 is compared to X = -5 and Z = 5, what is the expected result?

Comment: @GalAbraGal I need a comparison that shows a different result if the class has not the same coordinates. The sum that I am making will not work because it will show the same result if the x and z are swapped.

Comment: @chicoferreira it would mean that items are sorted first by the first coordinate, and then by the second coordinate, like how in a dictionary words are sorted first by the first letter and then by the second letter and so on

Comment: @harold that should solve my issue. Let me test it. Really thanks <3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved with:

```java
    @Override
    public int compareTo(@Nonnull Position2D position2D) {
        int xComparison = Integer.compare(this.getX(), position2D.getX());
        int zComparison = Integer.compare(this.getZ(), position2D.getZ());

        return xComparison != 0 ? xComparison : zComparison;
    }
```

Special thanks to [@harold](https://stackoverflow.com/users/555045/harold).